# Updating a ParameterSyntaxList is not updating the code in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I am trying to write a small refactoring which breaks method/actor parameters apart like this:

Before:

```
public void Method(string a, string b, string c)
{
}
```

After refactoring:

```
public void Method(string a, 
                   string b, 
                   string c)
{
}
```

The code for the refactoring is below, but the problem is that the code formatting doesn't change in Visual Studio. When debugging - I can see that the `updatedParameterList` is correctly formatted. What am I missing?

```
private async Task<Document> BreakParametersApart(Document document, ParameterListSyntax parameterListNode, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ParameterSyntax firstParameter = parameterListNode.Parameters.First();

    int column = firstParameter.GetLocation().GetLineSpan().StartLinePosition.Character;

    StringBuilder paddingBuilder = new StringBuilder("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
        paddingBuilder.Append(" ");
    string padding = paddingBuilder.ToString();

    List<ParameterSyntax> updatedParameters = new List<ParameterSyntax>();
    updatedParameters.Add(firstParameter.WithoutLeadingTrivia().WithoutTrailingTrivia());

    foreach (ParameterSyntax parameter in parameterListNode.Parameters.Skip(1).ToList())
        updatedParameters.Add(parameter.WithoutLeadingTrivia().WithoutTrailingTrivia().WithLeadingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.Whitespace(padding)));

    ParameterListSyntax updatedParameterList = SyntaxFactory.ParameterList(parameterListNode.OpenParenToken, SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(updatedParameters), parameterListNode.CloseParenToken);

    SyntaxNode root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);
    var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(parameterListNode, updatedParameterList);
    return document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. To insert a new line I had to use the `EndOfLine` trivia:

`.WithLeadingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.EndOfLine("\n"), SyntaxFactory.Whitespace(padding))`

Comment: One nitpick: avoid hardcoding \n, since you'll want to use the line ending format of the file you're in. One approach might be to go the trailing trivia of the ) and grab any EndOfLine trivia that's there. Or do other things as well.